# Undefined symbols _RCTRegisterModule

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm using xcode 13,
React-native version 0.64.2

Its working fine in Android but iOS I getting error

It builds with the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_RCTRegisterModule", referenced from:
+[RNMixpanel load] in RNMixpanel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Undefined symbol: _RCTRegisterModule

Comment: I got very similar, I believe it's to do with no longer using the legacy build system.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if it's the same thing but for me my solution was an issue with the packages, they had `s.dependancy` as React when it should be React-Core. See here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29633#issuecomment-694187116

You can manually change them to see if it works for you and then use the patcher as suggested to fix the libraries.

Comment: This just got me on a library I maintain. Most libraries have moved to a React-Core dependency now, but it appears to me that you will only notice this error if you use static frameworks in your react-native Podfile. That is still rare so it may not always show up for a library, leaving this little landmine there waiting to get you. Changing the s.dependency (via patch-package if needed) to React-Core and you will probably be able to build. Thanks @Aequitas

Comment: Any chance someone can link to a tutorial for this?